# While loop makes page reload very slow

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have 1 while loop in a function in javascript, the function doesn't get called when the page loads, but when I comment the while loop out, the reload time of the webpage is pretty much instant. When the while loop isn't commented out, it takes 6 seconds to reload the page.

Why does this slow down loading time so much, and how do I make the page load faster without removing functionality?

*(the purpose of the code is to select multiple files, and when the files are selected, displaying them in a list)*

**Javascript**

```
function first(){
    putin=$('#putin');
    input=document.getElementById('putin');
    list=document.getElementById('list');
    putin.change(function(){
        files();
    });
}
a=true;
function files(){
    i=0;
    if(input.files.length==1){
        document.getElementById('label').innerHTML=input.files.length+' File selected';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('label').innerHTML=input.files.length+' Files selected';
    }
    if(a){
        while(i<input.files.length){
            list.innerHTML+=input.files[i].name+'<br/>';
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title id='title'>Select Files</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="selector.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="first()">
        <div id='wrap'>
            <label id="label" for="putin">Select files to play!</label>
            <input id='putin' type="file" multiple accept="audio/*,video/*">
        </div>
        <div id='list'>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

*Btw this is my first time posting here, and i'm Dutch, so there probably will be spelling and or grammar mistakes, sorry for that*

Comment: Concatenating `innerHTML` is very expensive.  You should build your HTML separately and insert it all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript runs in two passes.  A first pass that sets up variables and functions and then the second when you run your code.

So, even though you don't run that code the first pass goes over it analyzing it and setting up the scope it'll run in.  So even though you haven't run it there is a potential performance impact.  Doing something akin to this may help:

```
while(i<input.files.length){
    tmp +=input.files[i].name+'<br/>';
    i++;
 }
list.innerHTML += tmp;
```

But, interestingly, I put your code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rMpOAZIikiDuOl1J4otB?p=info

And I looked at the performance and memory usage graphs in chrome developer's tools with and without those lines commented out and didn't see a significant difference.  And they seem to run at similar speeds overall.

So there may be more going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of comments: Don't access functions or function results until you need them; create string variables then assign them.  Use default values and change only if needed.  Cache the jQuery object variable $myObject rather rebuilding the jQuery object.  Don't use jQuery for native functions, instead $myObject[0].id = .... Use specificity for faster jquery finds, eg $(body #container > #results > .items).  Change the "if(a)" to do... while since it always runs once.  Put your functions in an anonymous object for error and scope containment.

The html is light so it's likely your uploads, network or computer.  This is free-typed but might help:

```
. . . . </body>
<script>
(function($) {
    var $input = $('body .container input#fileInput');
    $input.change(function() { 
        var $this = $(this), 
        n = $this.files.length, files = '';
        $($this[0].files).each(function(a, b) { 
            files += '\n<li>Item '+ a +',  '+ b +'</li>';
        });
        $input.append('File(s) Selected:'+ n);
        $('body .container #file-list').append(files);
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
```